# XLSXWriter - Center Alignment doesn't work with set_column using a Format object

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have been trying to format my Excel Output by center-aligning horizontally and vertically my columns. However, when checking the exported xlsx file, **everything is still left-aligned**. One explanation I found is :

> In XlsxWriter, as in Excel, a cell format overrides a column format.

Do I need to go over every one of my cells to apply the desired format to it ?
Thank you for your help !

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Analyse PRM.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
analyse_prm.style.apply(highlight_prm, axis = None).to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Cohérence PRM DR - PIX-F', index=False)
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Cohérence PRM DR - PIX-F']

worksheet.set_zoom(90)

max_row = len(analyse_pixf.index)
max_col = len(analyse_pixf.columns)
worksheet.autofilter(0, 0, max_row, max_col - 1)

cell_format = workbook.add_format()
cell_format.set_align('center')
cell_format.set_align('vcenter')

#Column width & format
worksheet.set_column('A:J',20, cell_format)

writer.save()
```

Comment: I ran some tests with dummy data and it seems to turn out correctly. Your code seems fine. Do you have lots of dates/datetimes in those columns? In the xlsxwriter documentation, there are specific sections for Pandas - [Working with Pandas](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html) and [Example Pandas column formats](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_column_formats.html#ex-pandas-column-formats). The docs state: "It isn’t possible to format any cells that already have a format ... or any cells that contain dates or datetimes."

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Alan. I can confirm that the problem came from the use of `style.apply` that applies a format to the dataframe before exporting it, which is as you point it out not compatible with how xslxwriter works.